# How can I search through my routes for specific data?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have routes defined:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: comp, children: [
    { path: 'path1', component: comp1, children: [
      { path: 'child1', component: path1child1, data: { myData: 'myData1'},
      { path: 'child2', component: path2child2, data: { myData: 'myData2'},
    ]},
    { path: 'path2', component: comp2, data: { myData: 'myData3'}, children: [
      { path: 'child1', component: path2child1, data: { myData: 'myData4'},
    ]},
    { path: 'path3', component: comp3}
  ...
```

I ultimately want to navigate to the first route that has `myData` set to `'myData2'`.

I tried injecting `{ Router } from "@angular/router"` and searching the `this.router.config` array for my data, but this only gave me the child path `child2` and not the entire path I'd need to navigate to it, `path1/child2`. I could manually build these in my search function, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

How can I search for a route with specific data?

Answer (score 0):

Inject ROUTES

```
 @Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: `
   <div>
     <h2>Routes {{routes | json}}</h2>

      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
 `,
 })
 export class App {
  routes;
  constructor(@Inject(ROUTES) routes: any) {
   this.routes = routes;
 }
}
```